# Find function won't fetch related entity in Symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have a weird issue with Doctrine. I have set up the following structure:

Hers is ProfilRadnogMjestasPoslov Entity class

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProfilRadnogMjestasPoslovRepository::class)
 */
 class ProfilRadnogMjestasPoslov
 {

/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Description of the applicable level of competence.
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=1024, nullable=true)
 */
private $posloviRadnogMjesta;

public function getPosloviRadnogMjesta(): ?string
{
    return $this->posloviRadnogMjesta;
}

public function setPosloviRadnogMjesta(?string $posloviRadnogMjesta): self
{
    $this->posloviRadnogMjesta = $posloviRadnogMjesta;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=ProfilRadnogMjesta::class, inversedBy="profilRadnogMjestasPoslova")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="profil_radnog_mjesta_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $profilRadnogMjesta;

public function __construct()
{

}

public function getProfilRadnogMjesta(): ?ProfilRadnogMjesta
{
    return $this->profilRadnogMjesta;
}

public function setProfilRadnogMjesta(?ProfilRadnogMjesta $profilRadnogMjesta): self
{
    $this->profilRadnogMjesta = $profilRadnogMjesta;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\WorkArea")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="podrucje_rada_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $workArea;

public function getWorkarea(): ?WorkArea
{
    return $this->workArea;
}

public function setWorkarea(?WorkArea $WorkArea): self
{
    $this->workArea = $WorkArea;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $podrucje_rada_id;

public function getPodrucjeRadaId(): ?int
{
    return $this->podrucje_rada_id;
}

public function setPodrucjeRadaId(?int $podrucje_rada_id): self
{
    $this->podrucje_rada_id = $podrucje_rada_id;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $slozenost_poslova_id;

public function getSlozenostPoslovaId(): ?int
{
    return $this->slozenost_poslova_id;
}

public function setSlozenostPoslovaId(?int $slozenost_poslova_id): self
{
    $this->slozenost_poslova_id = $slozenost_poslova_id;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Job")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="slozenost_poslova_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $job;

public function getJob(): ?Job
{
    return $this->job;
}

public function setJob(?Job $job): self
{
    $this->job = $job;

    return $this;
}`
```

ProfilRadnogMjesta Entity

```
 /**
  * @ORM\Entity()
  */
class ProfilRadnogMjesta
{
const EDIT_ROUTE = 'job_profile_edit';

/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;
/**
 * Job title - (select from Radna mjesta).
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $nazivRadnogMjesta;
/**
 * Broj izvršitelja - Executor number.
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $brojIzvrsitelja;
/**
 * Kategorija radnog mjesta - Job category - selecting from table.
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $kategorijaRadnogMjesta;
/**
 * Pod kategorija - Sub Category - selecting from table.
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $podKategorija;
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=ProfilRadnogMjestasUtility::class,    mappedBy="profilRadnogMjesta", cascade={"persist","remove"})
 */
private $profilRadnogMjestasUtility;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=ProfilRadnogMjestasRukovodece::class, mappedBy="profilRadnogMjesta", cascade={"persist","remove"})
 */
private $profilRadnogMjestasRukovodece;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=ProfilRadnogMjestasKvalifikacije::class, mappedBy="profilRadnogMjesta", cascade={"persist","remove"})
 */
private $profilRadnogMjestasKvalifikacije;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=ProfilRadnogMjestasPoslov::class, mappedBy="profilRadnogMjesta", cascade={"persist","remove"})
 */
private $profilRadnogMjestasPoslov;

######## Constructor Starts ########
/**
 * @param $id
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->profilRadnogMjestasUtility = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->profilRadnogMjestasRukovodece = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->profilRadnogMjestasKvalifikacije = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->profilRadnogMjestasPoslov = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $id
 * @return ProfilRadnogMjesta
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getNazivRadnogMjesta(): ?string
{
    return $this->nazivRadnogMjesta;
}

/**
 * @param string $nazivRadnogMjesta
 * @return ProfilRadnogMjesta
 */
public function setNazivRadnogMjesta(string $nazivRadnogMjesta): ProfilRadnogMjesta
{
    $this->nazivRadnogMjesta = $nazivRadnogMjesta;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getBrojIzvrsitelja(): ?string
{
    return $this->brojIzvrsitelja;
}

/**
 * @param string $brojIzvrsitelja
 * @return ProfilRadnogMjesta
 */
public function setBrojIzvrsitelja(string $brojIzvrsitelja): ProfilRadnogMjesta
{
    $this->brojIzvrsitelja = $brojIzvrsitelja;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getKategorijaRadnogMjesta(): ?string
{
    return $this->kategorijaRadnogMjesta;
}

/**
 * @param string $kategorijaRadnogMjesta
 * @return ProfilRadnogMjesta
 */
public function setKategorijaRadnogMjesta(string $kategorijaRadnogMjesta): ProfilRadnogMjesta
{
    $this->kategorijaRadnogMjesta = $kategorijaRadnogMjesta;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getPodKategorija(): ?string
{
    return $this->podKategorija;
}



/**
 * @return Collection|ProfilRadnogMjestasPoslov[]
 */
public function getProfilRadnogMjestasPoslov(): ?Collection
{
    return $this->profilRadnogMjestasPoslov;
}

public function addProfilRadnogMjestasPoslov(ProfilRadnogMjestasPoslov $profilRadnogMjestasPoslov): self
{
    if (!$this->profilRadnogMjestasPoslov || !$this->profilRadnogMjestasPoslov->contains($profilRadnogMjestasPoslov)) {
        $this->profilRadnogMjestasPoslov[] = $profilRadnogMjestasPoslov;
        $profilRadnogMjestasPoslov->setProfilRadnogMjesta($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeProfilRadnogMjestasPoslov(ProfilRadnogMjestasPoslov $profilRadnogMjestasPoslov): self
{
    if ($this->profilRadnogMjestasPoslov->contains($profilRadnogMjestasPoslov)) {
        $this->profilRadnogMjestasPoslov->removeElement($profilRadnogMjestasPoslov);
        // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
        if ($profilRadnogMjestasPoslov->getProfilRadnogMjesta() === $this) {
            $profilRadnogMjestasPoslov->setProfilRadnogMjesta(null);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

In my controller :

```
    $id = $request->get('id');
    $repository = $this->entityManager->getRepository(ProfilRadnogMjesta::class);
    $profit = $repository->find($id);

    $html = $this->twig->render('reports/profit-report.html.twig', [
        'profit' => $profit,.....
```

In my Twig :

```
<td class="" width="46%">{{ profit.posloviRadnogMjesta }}</td>
```

So I get this error `Neither the property "posloviRadnogMjesta" nor one of the methods "posloviRadnogMjesta()", "getposloviRadnogMjesta()"/"isposloviRadnogMjesta()"/"hasposloviRadnogMjesta()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "App\Entity\ProfilRadnogMjesta".`

Does anybody know why this error occurs and how I can fix it? Is something wrong with my mapping?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. `getPosloviRadnogMjesta` is defined in the first entity but not the second. Update the code or call the relevant class in `getRepository`.

Comment: Is normal to not define `getPosloviRadnogMjesta` in the first entity because is related "ManyToOne" to it by an `ID`, can you clarify more your suggestion by code?

Answer (score 0):

The code fetchs one object through the repository:

```php
$repository = $this->entityManager->getRepository(ProfilRadnogMjesta::class);
```

The Twig code will try to fetch `posloviRadnogMjesta`:

```
{{ profit.posloviRadnogMjesta }}
```

So it will try to call `getPosloviRadnogMjesta()` and `isposloviRadnogMjesta()`.

But the method `getPosloviRadnogMjesta()` **only exists** in the entity `ProfilRadnogMjestasPoslov`.

---

So you have to move the method `getPosloviRadnogMjesta()` in the class `ProfilRadnogMjesta` or call the repository for the other class:

```
$repository = $this->entityManager->getRepository(ProfilRadnogMjestasPoslov::class);
```

Comment: Yes I understand but we have a relation ManytoOne between them so with ID in `posloviRadnogMjesta ` will call `getPosloviRadnogMjesta ` in `ProfilRadnogMjestasPoslov `, because `posloviRadnogMjesta `is a field in `ProfilRadnogMjestasPoslov ` table, I can't have 2 name of getter in 2 entities?!

Comment: `getPosloviRadnogMjesta()` returns a string so it won't use the relation.